# GitLab CI/CD integration with SonarQube. Connection refused

Tags: gitlab, sonarqube, gitlab-ci

So this is the problem I get:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar (default-cli) on project user_ingredient_service: Unable to execute SonarScanner analysis: Fail to get bootstrap index from server: Failed to connect to /127.0.0.1:9000: Connection refused -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.1.2184:sonar (default-cli) on project user_ingredient_service
```

My gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
image: maven:latest
stages:
  - test
  - sonarqube
  - build
variables:
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.m2/repository"
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "--batch-mode --errors --fail-at-end --show-version"
  DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://docker:2375"
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
.maven-cache: &maven_cache
  key: maven-cache-${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
  paths:
    - ".m2/repository/"
    - "target/"
.sonar_cache: &sonar_cache
  key: "${CI_JOB_NAME}"
  paths:
    - .sonar/cache
services:
  - name: docker:dind
    command: ["--tls=false"]
tests:
  stage: test
  variables:
    TESTCONTAINERS_HOST_OVERRIDE: "host.docker.internal"
  cache:
    - *maven_cache
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS test
  only:
    changes:
      - "**/*.jar"
      - "**/application-test.yml"
sonarqube-check:
  stage: sonarqube
  services: []
  variables:
    SONAR_USER_HOME: "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.sonar"
    GIT_DEPTH: "0"
  cache:
    - *maven_cache
    - *sonar_cache
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS verify sonar:sonar -Dsonar.qualitygate.wait=true -DskipTests
  only:
    - merge_requests
    - master
build:
  stage: build
  cache:
    - *maven_cache
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS package -DskipTests
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/*.jar
    expire_in: 1 day
  only:
    - master
```

This is my docker compose that runs SonarQube server:

```
version: '3.5'

services:

  sonarqube:
    image: sonarqube
    container_name: sonarqube
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      SONAR_ES_BOOTSTRAP_CHECKS_DISABLE: true
      SONAR_JDBC_USERNAME: sonartest
      SONAR_JDBC_PASSWORD: sonartest
      SONAR_JDBC_URL: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/postgres
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
      - sonarqube_conf:/opt/sonarqube/conf
      - sonarqube_data:/opt/sonarqube/data
      - sonarqube_extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions
      - sonarqube_bundled-plugins:/opt/sonarqube/lib/bundled-plugins

  db:
    image: postgres:14.4-alpine
    container_name: db
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: sonartest
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: sonartest
    volumes:
      - postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
      - postgresql_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data


 volumes:
      sonarqube_conf:
      sonarqube_data:
      sonarqube_extensions:
      sonarqube_bundled-plugins:
      postgresql:
  postgresql_data:
```

I passed SONAR_HOST_URL and SONAR_TOKEN to GitLab variables.
I can get through localhost:9000 in browser and SonarQube works, but it's won't to work in GitLab CI/CD and I absolutely don't understand why. Need help.

UPDATE

I run gitlab-runner in docker with next config: `docker run -d --privileged --name gitlab-runner --restart always -v /srv/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest`

and using docker as executor.
Config.toml:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0
shutdown_timeout = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "docker_runner"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  id = 22544272
  token = "qLHR_M5XyeJaBzmAc4zr"
  token_obtained_at = 2023-04-10T09:45:42Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.cache]
    Insecure = false
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", "/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
```

Comment: Please share your gitlab ci runner configuration as what you ask about depends on it. Which [executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/) are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

error is obvious: `[ERROR] ... Failed to connect to /127.0.0.1:9000: Connection refused`

It depends on some factors. what kind of executor is your gitlab runner?

For instance if its docker/k8s it is connecting to the container loopback device not the localhost you are using on your system. so in this case instead of using localhost for `$SONAR_HOST_URL` you should set the correct address.

also if you haven't set `sonar.core.serverBaseURL` in sonar config or `$SONAR_CORE_SERVERBASEURL` in your docker-compose or from your administration panel in sonar web then it might use loopback by default and redirect sonar scanner to `localhost`(does not matter what you set for `$SONAR_HOST_URL` in your ci pipeline. you need to set correct value here too).

### Update

No container IP address is ephermal and it might get changed unless you set it manually in your docker-compose. best option is to use a DNS or at least forward sonar port to your host and use  your host static ip.

Keep in mind this IP/DNS should be accessible to your sonar scanner.

Comment: Yea, I using own runner which is spinning in docker. And I don't understand what u mean with that "also if you haven't set...".

Comment: What is correct address? It's IpAdrees that I can get from docker inspect?

Comment: @Charismatic: Please add all the relevant information you want to ask about into your question.